# Discord.jsv13 Select menu doesn't appear

Tags: discord, discord.js

I would like to do a set Welcome with Select menu but the menu doesn't appear

**[Code screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zcq7H.png)**

**[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hiir9.png)**

**[The Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2vHX.png)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typo in your code. When you send your `messageSelectMenu`, you spell components as `conponents`. Correct the spelling and you should be good to go. Note: You also don't use the embed even though you declare it. If you want to send it, you can do it by using: `interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] })`

Comment: I know that if the error happens due to a typo, you are just supposed to write a comment but since the OP's question would be fixed, I wrote an answer